# SML not detecting OS on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, sml, osx-elcapitan

I tried to install SML on OS X El Capitan (currently PB 6).

Unfortunately the command `sml` in the Terminal gives me the following error message:

```
sml: unable to determine architecture/operating system
```

I used [this question from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410879/unable-to-determine-os)

and changed the `_arch-n-opsys` file, so that it would recognize El Capitan:

```
  i386) ARCH=x86;
case `uname -r` in
  9*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.5 Leopard
  10*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.6 Snow Leopard
  11*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.7 Lion
  12*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
  13*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.9 Mavericks
  14*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.10 Yosemite
  15*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.11 El Capitan
  *) exit 1;;
esc;;
```

But I still get the same error message:

```
sml: unable to determine architecture/operating system
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You said you changed the `_arch-n-opsys`.  You mean `.arch-n-opsys`, right?  Do you have multiple versions of `sml` installed?  If so, run `which sml` from your command line, and make sure that the `.arch-n-opsys` file you are editing is in the same directory.  As a last (but non portable) resort, you should be able to replace

```
*) exit 1;;
```

with

```
*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.11 El Capitan
```

Comment: Well, the file is actually called `_arch-n-opsys` in my version of SML.. it's located in `/usr/local/smlnj/config`. Furthermore `which sml` gives me `/usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml`, so I'd say the directory should be the right one. Furthermore I only have one version of SML installed (it's the 110.78, the newest version). Replacing `*) exit 1;;` with your line also doesn't help..

Comment: So I take it there is not a `.arch-n-opsys` file in your `/usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml` directory?  If you open up the `sml` file you should find something that looks like `ARCH_N_OPSYS="$BIN_DIR/.arch-n-opsys"`.  This is the config file that your `sml` file is using, I'd just like to verify that we are modifying the correct one.

Comment: I think the best way is to show you a screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/qgs78ws. The screenshot shows you the content of `/usr/local`. I've edited the file which is marked in blue.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out! This was actually the wrong file, to find the arch-n-opsys which starts with the . and not with the _, I had to enable that hidden files are visible. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: man, I'm somewhat appalled that OP didn't upvote and accept considering it obviously solved it for him... Saved my ass with this for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update brew to the latest version with `brew update` first.

Then reinstall `smlnj` with `brew remove smlnj` and `brew install smlnj`, or `brew upgrade smlnj`.